# How can I extend UITextField without losing functionality?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, textfield

I need to extend my UITextField class in order to store some additional properties:

```
class UICustomTextField : UITextField{
    var item = Item()
}
```

But when I do this:

```
let textField = UICustomTextField()
```

The keyboard covers up the TextField. Without extending the class it and use of UITextField directly it works.

There is any workaround ?

Comment: The keyboard will cover up the text field wether or not you use your custom text field. You have to move the text field out of the way. There are many questions on Stack Overflow regarding this.

Comment: You can use TPKeyboard, IQkeyboardManager lib. They will manage textfields position when keyboard is open